# using checkbox to enable textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textfield

i have an application here in winforms that am trying to make. This is how i want it to happen: whenever the user clicks on register visitor button the registration form should be opening. works fine. here is the function that is called in that case:

```
private void Register_Visitor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

On this form i have a textfield placed which i want to disable when the form loads. i wrote a line which disables the textbox on form load:

```
textbox1.enabled = false;
```

i placed the above line in the load function which is working fine. now i want to enable my textbox1 based on the checkbox checked. for this i wrote the code:

```
CheckState state = checkBox1.CheckState;
            switch (state)
            {
                case CheckState.Checked:
                    {
                        textBox1.Enabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                case CheckState.Indeterminate:
                case CheckState.Unchecked:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
```

now when i place the code above in the page load function nothing happens which is surely going to happen as that function is only called on form load. what am not getting is where to place the checkbox code so that my textbox is enable on runtime. other function are in response to button but what i want here it to instantly enable the textfield on runtime when the user checks the checkbox. kindly explain me how am i going to accomplish this!

Comment: try doing the code in the check changed event of check box.

Comment: make checked event of the checkbox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `CheckStateChanged` event; so whatever reason the `checkBox1` is checked/unchecked/grayed you'll have the `textBox1` properly enabled/disabled

```
private void checkBox1_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  textBox1.Enabled = (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked);
}
```

Comment: Isn´t textBox1.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked; even better?

Comment: @Somachr: it will be if you don't have to deal with *grayed* states; since `CheckState.Indeterminate` has been mentioned in the question, I think it'll be safer to declare the state expilitly.

Answer (score 0):

you are placing code at wrong event.

Instead of placing in `pageload` place that code on `chekchange` event of checkbox.

That will help you.

```
private void chkDisable_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        {
            textBox1.Enable=true;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Enable=false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the above code inside the function which handles the event for check box. 
In your case it is `checkchanged` status.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a hybrid of some of the above answers and it worked perfectly. I wanted the state of a button to be disabled upon loading the form, but then enabled if the user checks a box, here's the code:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       button1.Enabled = (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }


    }
```